# Why are two different results returned when using following two shift operator statements in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

When:

```
byte[] b = {-128, 0, 0, 0};
long total = 0;
```

The first expression returns -2,147,483,648:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
   int shift = (b.length - 1 - i) * 8;
   total += (b[i] & 255) << shift;
}
```

The second returns 2,147,483,648:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
   int shift = (b.length - 1 - i) * 8;
   long tmp = (b[i] & 255);
   total += tmp << shift;
}
```

My question is; why is the first statement positive and the second negative when they appear to be the same statement?

Comment: It would help if you'd post a short but *complete* program. The first statement wouldn't compile, to start with...

Comment: What is `b`? What is `i`? What is `shift`? What is `total`? More info needed.

Comment: OP, this still doesn't compile.

Comment: I do apologise, I realised after I posted...

Comment: Didn't you forget to update the `shift`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
total += (b[i] & 255) << shift;
```

the parenthesized expression is of type `int` and the left shift sets its leftmost bit to one, making it a negative number. The conversion to `long` happens only after all the calculation is done.

```
long tmp = (b[i] & 255);
```

Here the expression is `long` and the leftmost bit will stay zero after the shift.

If you want to keep the first expression, just add a cast to `long` for the parenthesized expression or use a `long` constant `255L`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So changing it to:

total += (long)(b[i] & 255) << shift;

would solve that

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `total += (b[i] & 255L) << shift;`

Comment: And once again comes along @PeterLawrey with the super-elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

shifting an int into the sign bit results in a negative number
shifting a long by the same amount results in a positive number

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following code you may understand what is going on :

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-2147483648));
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(2147483648L));
```

It prints

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

The same bits are interpreted differently for `long` and `int`.